# Redis - Delete/pop if more than x members in set

Tags: performance, redis

In Redis, I have millions of sets with varying quantities of members.

I want to reduce the overall size and really only need the latest members added to a set.

Is there an operation to pop/delete any members for each key until the total length is 10 or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using "sorted sets" instead of simple sets and use [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD), setting the scores to seconds since the epoch or something similar.  Then you can [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) to perform mass removals of old items.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SCARD` do get a Set's size - for each set you can do `SRANDMEMBER` and `SREM` until the Set gets to the required size.

Regular Sets don't track insertion time, but if you switch to Sorted Sets you can keep the timestamp as the score. Then, whenever you add a member, check to see if the max size has been reached and remove extra members as needed. Wrapping this in Lua is trivial and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use [Capped Lists](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#capped-lists), SETs doesn't support such functionality.